# storing ID's in array in loop wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a strange situation.

I want to store the IDs from a wp_query in a variable.

So far i have the following:

```
    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'programma',
    'post_parent'       =>  0,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    
) );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ): 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $ids[] = get_the_ID();
```

Now the strange thing is: when i print_r($ids), i get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 5404 ) 
Array ( [0] => 5404 [1] => 5307 )
Array ( [0] => 5404 [1] => 5307 [2] => 5308 )
```

Why is this? And how can i prevent this? I only want the last array to be stored.

Comment: Can you provide the full code ? (with the `var_dump`)

Comment: the print_r is inside your loop?

Comment: @HowardE: yes print_r is in this case inside the loop, but i printed it outside the loop as well, same result.

Comment: @Bazaim: var_dump results in: 
array(1) { [0]=> int(5404) } array(2) { [0]=> int(5404) [1]=> int(5307) } array(3) { [0]=> int(5404) [1]=> int(5307) [2]=> int(5308) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `print_r`is inside the loop, you see the construction of your array.

You may only want to get list of `ids`:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter

```
$ids = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'         => 'programma',
    'post_parent'       =>  0,
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'fields'            => 'ids'
]);
```

Comment: You are right, the error was(is) the print inside the loop.... Thanks!